# Move a GameObject from point A to point B - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, move

for the game I 'm creating I was trying to create a mega start that take you 750 meters ahead, but when trying to do this with vector3.lerp this is done instantly , and after trying many things he could not get it to work.

Here is the script that i wrote

```
       if (in750Run)
    {
        PlayerManager.Instanse.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(PlayerManager.Instanse.gameObject.transform.position,PowerUpFinalePlayer.position, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, PowerUpFinaleCamera.position, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        if (Vector3.Distance(PlayerManager.Instanse.gameObject.transform.position, PowerUpFinalePlayer.position) > 2)
        {
            in750Run = false;
        }
    }
```

If you have a better way of doing this, please replay to this post :)

Comment: Please note the unity tag is not for this kind of questions.

Comment: This kind of question, "if you have a better way of doing this", is better be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1) If you need smooth rotate to the target use:

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
```

2) To set a speed:

```
myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```